# SQL relationships between tables

Tags: sql

it might sound stupid.
can we have a database containing some tables without relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, though you may want to ask yourself if you really need a database. 
Though it can be convenient to have some database mechanisms such as transactions, automated backups, a standardized query language and whatnot without actually needing relations between tables.